# Binding to dependancy property is not displaying value when bound

Tags: xaml, binding, dependency-properties

I'm learning about `Dependency Properties`.

I have created a `Dependency Property` in a `UserControl` and within my `MainWindow`, I create an instance of the control and set the value. This works as expected.

My issues is when I try to use `Binding`.

So, my MainWindow XAML looks like (the StartTime type is string)

```
<Window x:Class="TimeLineCanvas.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:timeline="clr-namespace:TimeLineCanvas.UserControls"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding StartTime}" Height="100" /><!--Works binding to local property-->
            <timeline:TimeLine StartTime="28/01/2015" Height="100" /><!--Works when hard coded value-->
            <timeline:TimeLine StartTime="{Binding StartTime, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Height="100" /><!-- Does not display anything -->            
             <timeline:TimeLine x:Name="TimeLineInXaml" Height="100" /><!-- Works (value set in code behind) -->            
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace TimeLineCanvas
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        #region Constructors

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            SetStartTime(DateTime.Now);
            TimeLineInXaml.StartTime = _startTime; 
            this.DataContext = this;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Properties

        private string _startTime;
        public string StartTime
        {
            get
            {
                return _startTime;
            }
            set
            {
                _startTime = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("StartTime");
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region Methods

        internal void SetStartTime(DateTime dt)
        {
            this.StartTime = dt.ToShortDateString();
        }

        #endregion

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Implementation

        public void OnPropertyChanged(string PropertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        #endregion INotify
    }
}
```

My UserControl

```
<UserControl x:Class="TimeLineCanvas.UserControls.TimeLine"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <Canvas>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding StartTime, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        </Canvas>           
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

and the code behind in my UserControl

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace TimeLineCanvas.UserControls
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for TimeLine.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class TimeLine : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        #region Constructor

        public TimeLine()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Dependancy Properties

        public static readonly DependencyProperty StartTimeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "StartTime",
            typeof(string),
            typeof(TimeLine));

        #endregion

        #region Properties

        public string StartTime
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(TimeLine.StartTimeProperty); }
            set
            {
                DateTime result;
                if (!DateTime.TryParse(value, out result))
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(false, "Expected a value which can be converted to a DateTime");

                SetValue(TimeLine.StartTimeProperty, value);
            }
        }

        #endregion


        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Implementation

        public void OnPropertyChanged(string PropertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        #endregion INotify
    }
}
```

So, the issue is clear, it's the binding but I don't know how to solve this! Even my Voodoo programming (trying anything and everything in random order) based upon other suggestions (such as adding `DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}` to the UserControl, adding the INotifyPropertyChanged to both MainWindow and the UserContorl) does not affect the result.

What am I doing wrong or am I trying to do something it isn't intended for?

Comment: I'm sorry, my question is worded poorly and has left confusion. I've re-worded the question and re-posted it, please do shut this one down. Duplicate of [Dependancy Properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19792280/dependancy-properties)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is a little bit confusing because you have duplicate property names and have obviously tested a lot during "Voodoo programming". :)

However, I think I found your problem anyway. Try to remove the following line in your `TimeLine` class:

```
this.DataContext = this;
```

This should not be in the control, but only in the `MainWindow`.

**Explanation:**

In the MainWindow constructor you set the MainWindow's `DataContext` to itself. Child elements inherit their `DataContext` from their parent element if it is not explicitly set. Therefore, the `DataContext` of the `TextBlock` is also set to the MainWindow which is why the `Binding` works properly here. However, in all `TimeLine` instances, you set the `DataContext` explicitly to themselves (in the constructor), i.e. the `TimeLine` object. This way, the `Binding` on the `TimeLine` instance does not refer to the `MainWindow`'s `StartTime` property, but to the property with the same name in the `TimeLine` control. However, this property is never set to any real value (only bound to itself which does not make sense). Therefore, nothing is displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Nearly there just need to simplify your understanding of Binding. 
Remember you have 2 lots of binding here

MainWindow implements INotify with Property StartTime
TimeLine User Control has DP StartTime

So MainWindow is bound to property StartTime in MainWindow.cs NB Button to test change of time

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>          
        <timeline:TimeLine x:Name="myTime" StartTime="{Binding StartTime, Mode=TwoWay}" Height="100" /> 
        <Button Content="Change Time"  Width="200" Height="100" Click="Button_Click"/>                 
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Backend of MainWindow

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region Constructors

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();           
        this.DataContext = this;
            Loaded += (s, args) =>
            {
                this.myTime.StartTime = "Some Time";
            };
    }

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    private string _startTime;
    public string StartTime
    {
        get
        {
            return _startTime;
        }
        set
        {
            _startTime = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("StartTime");
        }
    }

    #endregion       

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Implementation

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string PropertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    #endregion INotify

     private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
     {
        // We are changing usercontrol StartTime DP which updates or property in main             //window
        this.myTime.StartTime = "A new TIME";
     }
}
```

}

UserControl (bound to DP in backend)

```
<Grid>
    <Canvas>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding StartTime}" />
    </Canvas>           
</Grid>
```

UserControl backend just has DP

```
public partial class TimeLine : UserControl
{
    #region Constructor

    public TimeLine()
    {
        InitializeComponent();           
    }

    public string StartTime
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(StartTimeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(StartTimeProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for StartTime.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty StartTimeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("StartTime", typeof(string), typeof(TimeLine), new PropertyMetadata(""));
}
```

Now when you click Change Time Button usercontrol updates MainWindow Property. 
Hope that helps

Comment: I'm a little lost, isn't this approach just setting the value directly to the UserControl on the button click? This isn't actually using the UserControl in the way it is intended. Or have I missed the point?

Comment: How did you want the usercontrol used? In your original code you have 2 properties of the same name so based my answer on that. Why do you even need a user control? are you using the usercontrol on multiple pages?

Comment: Yes, it will be used and I want it "plug and play". In otherwords, some one creates an instance of my control on their page, possibly multiple times per page, and I want them to only use the XAML and the control does what it needs to do!